# How to use dynamic_cast with for_each

Tags: c++, foreach, dynamic-cast

I have the following code:

```
vector<C1*>::iterator itr = vec.begin();
for (; itr != vec.end(); ++itr) {
  C2 *c = dynamic_cast<C2*>(*itr);
  c->f();
}
```

I am wondering if I could use one-line for_each to replace it. I tried the following:

```
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), bind2nd(mem_fun(&C2::f), dynamic_cast<C2*>));
```

But I get a compile error,

```
expected unqualified-id before 'dynamic_cast'
```

What should be the right then?

[EDIT] I cannot use c++11. Looks like I have to define an extra functor, sigh.

For some questionings about the code itself:
C1 and C2 are 2 pure interfaces; f() is only available as C2's API. The vector "vec" has a list of objects which have both C1 and C2 interfaces, but they are passed to this piece of code as vector of C1*.

Comment: Since you only have `C2`s in your vector, just have the vector type be `vector<C2*>`

Comment: Also, that bind could take `[](C1 *c1) { return dynamic_cast<C2 *>(c1); }` as its second argument.

Comment: The result of dynamic_cast should be tested, so I would be careful about trying to do everything in one line of code.  I agree with H2C03 that if every single instance can be a C2* then why is the vector a container of C1*?  Based on what you wrote, I think that you misunderstand what bind2nd does.  c2::f doesn't take any arguments at all so using it with a bind2nd call makes no sense.

Answer (score 6):

Under C++11, instead of doing all this `bind` stuff, I would use a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
for_each (vec.begin(), vec.end(), [] (C1* c1) 
{
  C2* c2 = dynamic_cast <C2*> (c1);
  if (c2)
  { 
    c2->f();
  }
});
```

If using C++11 isn't possible, or if for some other reason you shy away from this, then I would construct a [functor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) to wrap this in:

```
struct call_f
:
  public std::unary_function <C1*, void>
{
  void operator () (C1* c1) const
  {
    C2* c2 = dynamic_cast <C2*> (c1);
    if (c2)
    {
      c2->f();
    }
  }
};

// ...

for_each (vec.begin(), vec.end(), call_f());
```

Comment: Now the question of course is: If C++11 is available, why use a `for_each`?

Comment: It might be stylistically preferable to combine the declaration and the `if` statement: `if (C2* c2 = dynamic_cast<C2*>(c1)) { ... }`

Comment: @templatetypedef:  It *might* be.  I'll leave that to the reader to decide.

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic_cast<...>()` may look like a function but it isn't one. You could use something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct dynamic_cast_fun {
    template <typename F>
    T* operator()(F* from) const {
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(F* from);
    }
};
```

(possibly with some extra overloads to deal with the constness of the argument).